# Menu manage hover and click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a menu that I want to add hover and click events to.

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
}, function(){
    $(this).css('background', '');
});

$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'green');
});
```

Here is the demo:
 https://jsfiddle.net/u2dn68bg/18/

How can I stop my hover event from overriding the click event? i.e. if I have already clicked an element the hover event should not get triggered for that clicked element.

Comment: Just use css classes....

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS rules and toggle a class.

```js
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
})
```

```css
a.active, a.active:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">One</a>
<a href="#">Two</a>
<a href="#">Three</a>
<a href="#">Four</a>
```

based on your comment to not use CSS which is a bad design pattern....

```js
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let color = ''
  if (!this.dataset.active) {
    this.dataset.active = 1
    color = 'green'    
  } else {
    delete this.dataset.active
  }
  this.style.backgroundColor = color;
}).on("mouseenter mouseleave", function (e) {
  if (this.dataset.active) return
  const color = e.type === "mouseenter" ? "red" : ""
  this.style.backgroundColor = color;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">One</a>
<a href="#">Two</a>
<a href="#">Three</a>
<a href="#">Four</a>
```

Comment: Not allowed to create CSS files unfortunately, only jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Toggle a CSS class when the element is clicked. When you hover, only change the background if the element do not have that certain class.

```js
$('a').hover(function(){
    !$(this).hasClass('clicked') && $(this).css('background', 'red');
}, function(){
    !$(this).hasClass('clicked') && $(this).css('background', '');
});

$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'green').toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-inline menu list-unstyled">
  <li><a href="#">Section 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Section 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>
```